# FireBase - moving child(as is) to different path

Tags: swift, architecture, path, firebase, children

I'm creating a game. Each game constructed with two players(only). After i'm matching two players they are still on the same categories as the "unmatched users".

So as example

```
Parent
      UnMatchedUsers
                     User1 : unMatched
                     User2 : unMatched
                     User3 : unMatched
                     User4 : Matched
                     User5 : Matched
      MatchedUsers
```

How can i move both of the child completely to the new category(`MatchedUsers`)(`IOS`)? 
Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you already have some code and it doesn't do what you want or expect it to do. Show us a minimal example of the code that reproduces your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen , actually i used to just delete and create new object(which sound less effective), i will add the code as soon as i get back home. thanks for the notice.

Comment: Creating the new node and the deleting the old one is the right approach. Feel free to simply close, because the answer is likely going to be: "yes, that's the way to do it".

Comment: Alright, sounds fair. Before I'm closing, the main reason why i want to move categories is that when new users join the "unmatched" room I'm fetching all the users that their value is "unmatched", and I'm afraid that it a lot more less effective to store both states under one category(cuz it will search within "irrelevant" objects as well).On the other hand, maybe recreate then at a different branch might be less effective then the other.(im not familiar with FireBase core). In theory, if the app scales - what is the right approach? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: In NoSQL you should always model the data for how your application uses it. A great read may be: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen ,Thank u for the article.I tried to read it(like 10% of it), and i got completely lost. One of my (big) disadvantages as a developer, is not knowing, or sometimes(like now) not even understanding the behind process behind the scenes. I haven't got a straight answer on what approach to take from the article, yet my intuition went on the "delete and create on a different" strategy. Mainly because on a scaleable scenario, i'll prefer dynamic data between categories on irrelevant pile under one. Hope to hear your thought about this, please refer, Much thanks and appreciation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, yes; one option is to add data to the MatchedUsers node and remove it from the UnMatchedUsers node.

There may be another approach:

```
users
   user_id_0
     matched_to: user_id_3
   user_id_1
     matched_to: NO
   user_id_2
     matched_to: NO
   user_id_3
     matched_to: user_id_0
```

You probably have a  /users/ node anyway so the above will give you all kinds of flexibility:

- Easily find which users are not matched
- Know which users are matched, and who they are matched to
- No removing data, just update the matched_to node when they are matched
- All in a nice and tidy single node

You could even get crazy and add a sub-node for each user that tracks the history of who they were matched against or even their high scores!

Comment: Hey Jay! Thank you for  your answer ! Actually that's exactly what i am exactly doing now, the only different i have made, is when i "match" to users, i first adding both of them to new category parent/matchedUsers(at the completion- i delete then from parent/users) , and when the game is over i simply delete them from the matchedUsers category as well, so if the want play again with a diffrent player, im adding them back "as a new player" to the /users/ category. That way i  not making any irrelevant data lay at both of them. Is it a smart approach?

Comment: Any approach that works is usually a smart approach! If you don't need traceability on your matches, scores or other data then it should be fine.